# Proof of work: average number of tries to create a block

Tags: proof-of-work

First, I'm sorry if I'm asking a stupid question. I'm just trying to understand bitcoin. I'm reading the [Ethereum white paper](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/White-Paper#mining), and I couldn't understand this sentence about proof of work:

> At the current target of ~2^187, the network must make an average of
>   ~2^69 tries before a valid block is found

My question: how the 2^69 number of tries is computed?

---

### Updated:

My question: why 2^69 instead of 2^70 or 2^169?

Comment: Are you asking how to determine the number of tries required to solve a block given a difficulty target? Or are you asking what physical operations take place in order for a miner to "try" to solve a block?

Comment: The 69 is just 256-187 because the hashes are 256 bits long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MeshCollider's comment mentions, it is simply the difference between the total number of bits against the target bits.

As to why it is this way is just a function of probability. If you have a range of 1-100, and your target is `<= 20`, there are 20 numbers that satisfy your requirement. Thus, `20 * 1/100`, or 20 tries out of 100 should result in a valid  number against your target.

It works the same way, although on a much larger scale here. Your target and attempt are both 256 bits numbers, which means they range from 0 to `2^256-1`. If your target is `2^179`, it means that `256-179`, or `2^67` tries will, on average, produce a valid number against the target.